# Drop indicators with estfe

Tags: stata

When using `estfe` and subsequently `indicate(r(indicate_fe))`, the regression table contains *all* of the fixed-effects set up, even if I have not specified them in `estfe`, and there appears no way to drop them.

In the following example, I'd like to control for `headroom` and `foreign`, but only display `headroom`, which I rename to `foo`:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. reghdfe price weight, a(headroom foreign)
(dropped 1 singleton observations)
(converged in 4 iterations)

HDFE Linear regression                            Number of obs   =         73
Absorbing 2 HDFE groups                           F(   1,     64) =      64.50
                                                  Prob > F        =     0.0000
                                                  R-squared       =     0.5542
                                                  Adj R-squared   =     0.4985
                                                  Within R-sq.    =     0.5020
                                                  Root MSE        =  2095.7886

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      weight |    3.58106   .4458786     8.03   0.000     2.690315    4.471805
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    Absorbed |          F(7, 64) =      5.272   0.000             (Joint test)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Absorbed degrees of freedom:
---------------------------------------------------------------+
 Absorbed FE |  Num. Coefs.  =   Categories  -   Redundant     | 
-------------+-------------------------------------------------|
    headroom |            7               7              0     | 
     foreign |            1               2              1     | 
---------------------------------------------------------------+

. eststo m: reghdfe price weight, a(headroom foreign)
(dropped 1 singleton observations)
(converged in 4 iterations)

HDFE Linear regression                            Number of obs   =         73
Absorbing 2 HDFE groups                           F(   1,     64) =      64.50
                                                  Prob > F        =     0.0000
                                                  R-squared       =     0.5542
                                                  Adj R-squared   =     0.4985
                                                  Within R-sq.    =     0.5020
                                                  Root MSE        =  2095.7886

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      weight |    3.58106   .4458786     8.03   0.000     2.690315    4.471805
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    Absorbed |          F(7, 64) =      5.272   0.000             (Joint test)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Absorbed degrees of freedom:
---------------------------------------------------------------+
 Absorbed FE |  Num. Coefs.  =   Categories  -   Redundant     | 
-------------+-------------------------------------------------|
    headroom |            7               7              0     | 
     foreign |            1               2              1     | 
---------------------------------------------------------------+

. estfe m, labels(headroom "foo")

. return list

macros:
        r(indicate_fe) : " "foo=0.headroom"  "foreign=0.foreign""

. esttab m, keep(weight) indicate(`r(indicate_fe)')

----------------------------
                      (1)   
                    price   
----------------------------
weight              3.581***
                   (8.03)   

foo                   Yes   

foreign               Yes   
----------------------------
N                      73   
----------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001

. esttab m, keep(weight) indicate(`r(indicate_fe)') drop(foreign)
coefficient foreign not found
```

Clearly, `foreign` is still in the regression table, despite my hardest efforts to drop it or not show it. `help estfe` is not being of any use, so I'm afraid I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like rather than including `r(indicate_fe)` you want to include `displayName = coefficientName`, so in the example above and below, the `return list` shows:

`r(indicate_fe) : " "headroom=0.headroom" "foreign=0.foreign""`

so we indicate `foo = 0.headroom`

Using your example:

```
sysuse auto, clear
eststo m: reghdfe price weight, a(headroom foreign)
estfe m
return list
esttab m, keep(weight) indicate("foo = 0.headroom")
```

this will output:

```
----------------------------
                      (1)   
                    price   
----------------------------
weight              3.581***
                   (8.03)   

foo                   Yes   
----------------------------
N                      73   
----------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```